# Запретить выделение скрытых строк в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Используется `DataGrid` с возможностью множественного выбора.
Некоторые строки скрываются через триггер:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Проблема в следующем.

К примеру в таблице 10 строк. Строки 2-9 скрыты. Я выбираю первую строку, зажимаю <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> и кликаю на последнюю строку. В итоге в свойство `SelectedItems` попадают все строки.

Хотелось бы сделать какой-то триггер на подобие этого, но нельзя использовать одно и тоже свойства в качестве триггера и сеттера:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Как поправить такое поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подписаться на событие `SelectionChanged`, перебирать все строки, проверять их видимость и снимать выделение у скрытых строк.

Лучше пока ничего не придумал :)

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (object item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        int index = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(item);
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {
            row.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```